# Displaying framework message.error DJANGO

Tags: django, message

I am creating an app when a user can search for recipes by inputing some ingredients in search-field.

I would like to do that when search-field is empty or string is empty a user get error.message 'Please put input.' But after i have implemented message.error into views and template it only returns the same page without this informaton 'Please put input.'. Do you know what i made wrong here?

My views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db.models import Q #new

from .models import Recipe
from .models import Ingredient

from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def drink_list(request):
    template = "drinks/drink_list.html"
    return render(request, template)

def search_results(besos):

    query = besos.GET.get('q')

    if not query or query == ' ' or query == '  ' or query == '   ':
        messages.error(besos, "Please put input")
        return redirect('drink_list')

    else:
        q = Q()
        for queries in query.split():
            q |= (Q(ingredients__ingredient_name__icontains=queries))
            #why it look for 'sok z cytryny' and show as well sok z limonki
        results = Recipe.objects.filter(q)
        template = "drinks/search_results.html"
        context = {
        'results' : results,
        }
        return render(besos, template, context)
```

My template search_results:

```
{% if results %}
  {% for drink in results %}
    <div>
      <p>{{ drink.recipe_name }}</p>
      <p>Preparation: {{ drink.preparation }}</p>
      <p>Ingredients:
        {% for ingredient in drink.ingredients.all %}
          {{ingredient.ingredient_name}}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </p>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}

{% elif messages %}
<ul class="messages">
  {% for message in messages %}
  <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
  <div>Such ingredients do not exist</div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is no query term , you are currently redirecting to:

```
return redirect('drink_list')
```

but you are not passing the message on to the `drink_list` view.
In case of redirect, you can pass the message string as argument

```
return redirect('{}?message=Please put input'.format(reverse('drink_list)))
```

Then your `drink_list` template must include:

```
<ul class="messages">
  <li>{{ message }}</li>
</ul>
```

You need to further modify your `drink_list` function to get the message argument:

```
def drink_list(request):
    template = "drinks/drink_list.html"
    message = request.GET.get('message', ''))
    return render(request, template, message=message)
```

And finally your url must include the optional message argument :

```
path('drink_list/', views.drink_list,name='drink_list'),
```

Comment: then i get information NameError that message is not defined, but have added all you said. here it is how i look: def drink_list(request):
    template = "drinks/drink_list.html"
    return render(request, template, message=message)

def search_results(besos):

    query = besos.GET.get('q')

    if not query or query == ' ' or query == '  ' or query == '   ':
        messages.error(besos, "Please put input")
        message = "Plus put input"
        return redirect('drink_list', args=(message))

Comment: def drink_list(request) -- this also has to be changed to add message as extra argument. see how i have defined above, added an exrta optional argument message=""

Comment: now i have fixed this all and TypeError at /
drink_list() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'

Comment: django version 2.2.3, it did not help. i actually put this url: path('drink_list/<message>', views.drink_list, name='drink_list'),

Comment: TypeError at /
drink_list() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'

Comment: TypeError at /
render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'message'

Comment: the error is still the same:( TypeError at /
render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'message'

Comment: NoReverseMatch at /search/
Reverse for 'drink_list' with keyword arguments '{'args': ('Please put input',)}' not found. 3 pattern(s) tried: ['drink_list/$', 'drink_list/(?P<message>[^/]+)$', '$']

Comment: I have modified almost all the stuff to take a different route. I do not have django on my current machine so all the hit and trials

Comment: Hi, now i have found what was wrong. it was only to put this whole code containing {%  if messages %} from search result template to drink_list and now it is working. :)